# Show that a scalar integral over a parametrized curve is unchanged if you reparametrize it.

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that a scalar integral over the parametrized curve $(\ln (t), t, t)$ for $t \in [2, 4]$ is unchanged if the curve is reparametrized.

I have no idea how to show this.

Answer (score -1):

The parameterization is not unique. So can take any other parameters and solve the question .it will show the same.